# Appending text in Silverlight XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, combobox, telerik

Hi,

I have a Telerik combo box bound to a list of items. It displays them fine. All I wish to change is to append a property of another object to the start of the string in the combobox.

Currently, the combo box shows `"ListOfItems.Name"`, I would like it to show `"Object.Property --- ListOfItems.Name"`

```
   <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="radComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Something along the lines of

```
   <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="radComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}" DisplayMemberPath="String.Append(Object.Property --- Name)" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

How can I do this in my XAML code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand what it is you want to do, but if I have understood correctly you have to use the ItemTemplate property of the RadComboBox:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="radComboBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName, Mode=TwoWay}">
<telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Object.Property"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" --- "></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This will not work, as the binding for "<TextBlock Text="{Binding Object.Property}"></TextBlock>" does not show up (and it just prints the bare string "Object.Property" using your example).

Comment: Figured it out - had to reset the DataContext in the second binding! DataContext="{Binding Context}" and she worked. Thanks a lot! :)